# Porque se congela mi código Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, pygame

He estado haciendo un programa en Pygame que carga una imagen en la pantalla, y he introducido una cajita donde el usuario escribirá lo que vea/oiga (en un futuro habrá áudios). El problema consiste en que el programa se abre y acepta que el usuario escriba números, pero una vez le doy a la tecla ENTER la cajita deberías reiniciarse, pero no lo hace, y el programa se congela. Alguna solución?
InputBox es la cajita que se puede encontrar en mi github: https://github.com/Maskedllama/InputBox/blob/main/InputBox.py

```
import pygame
from InputBox import InputBox

pygame.init()
#Variables
yousayrun = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pointz = 0
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ''
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')

def main():
    pygame.init()
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400))
    surface.fill((255, 70, 90))
    imageaudio1 = pygame.image.load("ClickAudio1.png").convert()
    surface.blit(imageaudio1,(190,70))
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 50)
    punts = font.render("Puntuació: " + str(pointz), True, (255, 255, 255))
    surface.blit(punts, (350, 30))
    titolsuma3 = font.render("SUMA (3)", True, (0, 0, 0))
    surface.blit(titolsuma3, (10, 20))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Projecte MatZanfe")
    input_box.draw(surface)
    pygame.display.flip()

input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)

#Main Loop
while yousayrun:
    clock.tick(60)
    main()
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            yousayrun = False
            pygame.quit()
        else:
            result = input_box.handle_event(event)
            if result != None:
                if int(result) == int(input()):
                    pointz = pointz + 5

                input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```